# How to emit a cartesian product in TPL/Dataflow?

Tags: c#, dataflow, tpl-dataflow

I am trying to implement the following behaviour:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task ProducesCartesianProductOfInputs()
{
    var block = new CartesianProductBlock<int, string>();
    var target = new BufferBlock<Tuple<int, string>>();

    var left = block.Left;
    var right = block.Right;

    block.LinkTo(target);

    var actual = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();

    Assert.IsTrue(left.Post(1));
    Assert.IsTrue(right.Post("a"));
    Assert.IsTrue(left.Post(2));
    Assert.IsTrue(right.Post("b"));

    // PROBLEM?: These can run before messages have been processed and appear to abort further processing.
    left.Complete();
    right.Complete();

    while (await target.OutputAvailableAsync())
    {
        actual.Add(target.Receive());
    }

    var expected = new List<Tuple<int, string>>()
    {
        Tuple.Create(1, "a"),
        Tuple.Create(2, "a"),
        Tuple.Create(1, "b"),
        Tuple.Create(2, "b"),
    };

    CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(expected, actual.ToList());
}
```

My current (partial) implementation does not work and I can't figure out why:

```
// A block that remembers every message it receives on two channels, and pairs every message on a channel to every message on the other channel
public class CartesianProductBlock<T1, T2> : ISourceBlock<Tuple<T1, T2>>
{
    private TransformManyBlock<T1, Tuple<T1, T2>> left;
    private TransformManyBlock<T2, Tuple<T1, T2>> right;

    private List<T1> leftReceived = new List<T1>();
    private List<T2> rightReceived = new List<T2>();
    private List<ITargetBlock<Tuple<T1, T2>>> targets = new List<ITargetBlock<Tuple<T1, T2>>>();

    private object lockObject = new object();

    public ITargetBlock<T1> Left { get { return left; } }
    public ITargetBlock<T2> Right { get { return right; } }

    public CartesianProductBlock()
    {
        left = new TransformManyBlock<T1, Tuple<T1, T2>>(l =>
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                leftReceived.Add(l);
                // Pair this input up with all received alternatives
                return rightReceived.Select(r => Tuple.Create(l, r));
            }
        });
        right = new TransformManyBlock<T2, Tuple<T1, T2>>(r =>
        {
            lock(lockObject)
            {
                rightReceived.Add(r);
                // Pair this input up with all received alternatives
                return leftReceived.Select(l => Tuple.Create(l, r));
            }
        });
        Task.WhenAll(Left.Completion, Right.Completion).ContinueWith(_ => {
            // TODO: Respect propagate completion linkOptions. Defauting to propagation for now.
            foreach (var target in targets)
            {
                target.Complete();
            }
        });
    }

    private TaskCompletionSource<int> completion = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

    public Task Completion => completion.Task;

    public void Complete() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public void Fault(Exception exception) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

    public IDisposable LinkTo(ITargetBlock<Tuple<T1, T2>> target, DataflowLinkOptions linkOptions)
    {
        left.LinkTo(target);
        right.LinkTo(target);
        targets.Add(target);
        return null; // TODO: Return something proper to allow unlinking
    }

    public void ReleaseReservation(DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader, ITargetBlock<Tuple<T1, T2>> target)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool ReserveMessage(DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader, ITargetBlock<Tuple<T1, T2>> target)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Tuple<T1, T2> ConsumeMessage(DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader, ITargetBlock<Tuple<T1, T2>> target, out bool messageConsumed)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I'm experiencing the following (probably related) issues:

- It is non-deterministic. The test fails in different ways.
- It appears (from adding in logging, and also since I get anywhere from 3 to 6 output messages) that the `Complete` call to the two inputs is causing messages to not be processed, though my understanding is that it should allow all queues to drain first. (And if this is *not* the case, then I don't know how to write the test correctly.)
- It's quite possible my locking scheme is wrong/suboptimal, though my goal was to have something big and coarse that worked before trying to fix.
- My experiments with individual `TransformManyBlocks` has failed to come up with interesting surprising, and I can't figure out what's different in this case.

Comment: One small thing to check: if you use Post() instead of SendAsync(), make sure you check the return value and handle `false` appropriately. I believe that blocks decline messages beyond a single unprocessed message unless you attach a buffer, meaning that Post() will return false and the value you posted will be lost.

Comment: Ah good catch. In this case they're always returning true, but I have added assertions to verify for the future!

Comment: I'm beginning to suspect that not propagating completeness is contributing to my problems, but I can't quite articulate how yet. I seem to get more reliable results when I do that.

Comment: Most recent version of code with my attempt at handling completion that appears to work better maybe: https://github.com/xaviershay/ori-tracker/blob/master/MapStitcher/MapStitcher/CartesianProductBlock.cs (leaving original post because not sure if this is a red herring yet or not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suspected, this was related to completeness propagation. Here is a working version, including proper link disposable and respecting link options:

```
// A block that remembers every message it receives on two channels, and pairs every message on a channel to every message on the other channel
public class CartesianProductBlock<T1, T2> : ISourceBlock<Tuple<T1, T2>>
{
    private TransformManyBlock<T1, Tuple<T1, T2>> left;
    private TransformManyBlock<T2, Tuple<T1, T2>> right;

    private List<T1> leftReceived = new List<T1>();
    private List<T2> rightReceived = new List<T2>();
    private List<ITargetBlock<Tuple<T1, T2>>> targets = new List<ITargetBlock<Tuple<T1, T2>>>();

    private object lockObject = new object();

    public ITargetBlock<T1> Left { get { return left; } }
    public ITargetBlock<T2> Right { get { return right; } }

    public CartesianProductBlock()
    {
        left = new TransformManyBlock<T1, Tuple<T1, T2>>(l =>
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                leftReceived.Add(l);
                return rightReceived.Select(r => Tuple.Create(l, r)).ToList();
            }
        });
        right = new TransformManyBlock<T2, Tuple<T1, T2>>(r =>
        {
            lock(lockObject)
            {
                rightReceived.Add(r);
                return leftReceived.Select(l => Tuple.Create(l, r)).ToList();
            }
        });

        Task.WhenAll(Left.Completion, Right.Completion).ContinueWith(_ => {
            completion.SetResult(VoidResult.Instance);
        });
    }

    private TaskCompletionSource<VoidResult> completion = new TaskCompletionSource<VoidResult>();

    public Task Completion => completion.Task;

    public void Complete() {
        Left.Complete();
        Right.Complete();
    }

    public void Fault(Exception exception) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

    public IDisposable LinkTo(ITargetBlock<Tuple<T1, T2>> target, DataflowLinkOptions linkOptions)
    {
        var leftLink = left.LinkTo(target);
        var rightLink = right.LinkTo(target);

        var link = new Link(leftLink, rightLink);

        Task task = Task.FromResult(0);
        if (linkOptions.PropagateCompletion)
        {
            task = Task.WhenAny(Task.WhenAll(Left.Completion, Right.Completion), link.Completion).ContinueWith(_ =>
            {
                // If the link has been disposed of, we should not longer propagate completeness.
                if (!link.Completion.IsCompleted)
                {
                    target.Complete();
                }
            });
        }

        return link;
    }

    public void ReleaseReservation(DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader, ITargetBlock<Tuple<T1, T2>> target)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool ReserveMessage(DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader, ITargetBlock<Tuple<T1, T2>> target)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Tuple<T1, T2> ConsumeMessage(DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader, ITargetBlock<Tuple<T1, T2>> target, out bool messageConsumed)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private class Link : IDisposable
    {
        private IDisposable leftLink;
        private IDisposable rightLink;

        public Link(IDisposable leftLink, IDisposable rightLink)
        {
            this.leftLink = leftLink;
            this.rightLink = rightLink;
        }

        private TaskCompletionSource<VoidResult> completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<VoidResult>();
        public Task Completion { get { return completionSource.Task; } }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            leftLink.Dispose();
            rightLink.Dispose();
            completionSource.SetResult(VoidResult.Instance);
        }
    }

    private class VoidResult
    {
        public static VoidResult instance = new VoidResult();
        public static VoidResult Instance { get { return instance; } }

        protected VoidResult() { }
    }
}
```